# What Racket function can I use to insert a value into an arbitrary position within a list?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I know this is trivial to implement, but I want Racket to live up to it's "batteries included" promise. I am looking for a function that works something like this:

```
> (define (between lst item spot)
    (append (take lst spot)
            (cons item (drop lst spot))))
> (between '(1 3) 2 1)
'(1 2 3)
```

Does Racket include any such builtin?

Comment: I don't think so but [`split-at`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=split-at#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._split-at%29%29) is faster than doing a separate `take` and `drop`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an implementation based on Stephen Chang's comment (I swapped the argument order a little and renamed the function too):

```
(define (insert-at lst pos x)
  (define-values (before after) (split-at lst pos))
  (append before (cons x after)))
```

Comment: `(define (insert-at lst pos x)
  (call-with-values 
   (thunk (split-at lst pos))
   (λ (before after) (append before (cons x after)))))` Bleah, ok yours is better :)

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't; but yours is a good implementation!

If you had to implement it...

```
(define (between list item spot)
  (if (zero? spot)
      (cons item list)
      (let ((rslt list))
        (let looking ((list list) (indx (- spot 1)))
          (if (zero? indx)
              (begin (set-cdr! list (cons item (cdr list)))
                     rslt)
              (looking (cdr list) (- indx 1)))))))
```

Comment: Racket conses are immutable by default. So a non-mutating version is probably going to be a better fit.

Comment: This won't work in Racket, because pairs are immutable (no `set-cdr!`).